# How to get the title of the open inventory using a fabric 1.16.5 mod

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm using fabric 1.16.5 to develop a client-side mod for minecraft, and I am trying to get the title of the open inventory (see example below).

[image: inventory example]

In the example, the title is "Sell Items - 0" (with the emoji).

**What I've tried:**

- `MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.inventory.getName()` -> Returns "Inventory"
- `MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.inventory.getDisplayName()` -> Returns "Inventory"
- `MinecraftClient.getInstance().player.inventory.getCustomName()` -> Returns null

Because of the results, I'm guessing that inventory is returning the bottom inventory, the survival inventory.  How can I get the custom inventory provided by the server (the top inventory).

All help is appreciated.

Comment: there isn't a `player.openedinventory` ? Because for me, the given object `player.inventory` refer to the inv at the bottom

Comment: There is no ```player.openedinventory``` or similar.  I did point out in the post that I thought ```player.inventory``` was the bottom inventory.

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd have to go digging to find it.  Did you need it?

Comment: If you need lot of search, no. I think I have a way. But, if you find it again, you can self answer to your question

Comment: @Elikill58 9 months later but I've had another look at the question and figured out how to solve it.  Did you still need it?

Comment: Thanks for news. I think I fix it since this date too, I don't remember exactly for what I needed it. But it's perfect if you self-answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved through [Mixins](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:mixin_introduction).
More specifically, this can be achieved by Mixining into `HandledScreens`'s `open(ScreenHandlerType<T>, MinecraftClient, int, Text)` method.

First, create the mixin class and register it in your mod's `mod.mixins.json`'s client section.

```java
import net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.ingame.HandledScreens;
import org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.Mixin;

@Mixin(HandledScreens.class)
public class HandledScreensMixin {

}
```

Next, inject into the head of `open(ScreenHandlerType<T>, MinecraftClient, int, Text)`:

```java
@Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "open")
private static <T extends ScreenHandler> void open(ScreenHandlerType<T> type, MinecraftClient client, int id, Text title, CallbackInfo ci) {

}
```

In order to obtain a String version of the title, you can use `title.getString()`.
What you choose to do next depends on what your goal is.

For example, you could use a class with a getter and a setter so that you can access the value later.